# How to use properly the debug mode and release one in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to separate the behavior during debug and release in Android studio.

So I'm using `Build variants` like this.
[Build variants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtXdO.png)

So I added `BuildConfig.DEBUG` in my code.

I called the property like below in a service method.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Hello debug mode")
}
```

But the log output nothing. It seems the property did not be called.
How to use some functions in only debug mode environment or in only release mode.

Comment: Add android:debuggable="true" (default is false) to your Manifest inside the <application> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the import of BuildConfig is correct? Sometimes it can be using BuildConfig from a third party library and it is not the one of your project.
For example

```
import org.koin.android.BuildConfig
```

Make sure the import is something like this:

```
import com.yourpackagename.BuildConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue and I discovered that converse to previous behaviour where the Android Gradle Plugin generated the BuildConfig file for all modules, now they are no longer automatically generated as doing so in a multi-module app can affect build speed.

The new'ish approach is to enable this feature only in modules where it is  needed.

To do this, navigate to the module-level `build.gradle.kts` or `build.gradle` file of the module in which you need it and add the following to the `buildFeatures` closure within the larger `android` block like so:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct. Probably you have some filtering applied in your `Logcat` window which prevent display of this message?

You used `Log.e` which relates to `ERROR` level, so you can apply filter to display only error messages by typing `level:ERROR` [image]

Also you can read more about different Log levels https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Comment: No. I think naturally `BuildConfig.DEBUG` doesn't work